# Valve amp power supply filtering with centre tapped transformers

Tags: power-supply, rectifier, centre-tapped

I am designing a valve amplifier and am planning to use GU50 output pentodes in the power stage (PP). They can take up to 1kV on the anode but have an upper limit of 250V on the screen (which also seems to be the design point). This means that I need a 250V power supply for the screens but would prefer not to have two separate HT transformers. While my life would arguably be easier using, e.g. EL34s or 6550s, a possible benefit is the ability to use the 250V rail to also drive the preamp as this would avoid the need for a string of voltage dropping power resistors typically needed to power the preamp off the HT.

Whilst it is possible to get valve power transformers with two independent secondaries (which I believe would make it easy to stack DC supplies with independent bridge rectifiers) these are typically hard to find and a centre tapped configuration is far more common. Furthermore, the transformer I have is centre tapped as it is the only one I could find with two 180V windings (which will yield a little less than 250V DC each) and a sensible VA rating and heater current.

With this in mind, I am considering the following topologies:

[image: Centre tapped rectifier topologies]

If we consider the arrangement top left, this is the classic +/-V topology where the centre tap is connected to ground. I believe it is probably more "correct" to consider this to be grounding a point on the output of the supply rather than fixing a point on the transformer that is the input to the rectifier - but this is clearly a moot point as they amount to the same thing (but see next para).

If we want to create a +V/+2V instead then we can do this simply by moving the ground reference point on the output side of the supply, as shown with the arrangement in the top left. Note that in this case it is very important to ground the output side of the power supply as grounding one end of the transformer secondary would cause a short across one of the windings during half the cycle - this is the issue that is remedied by having independent secondaries.

Using this "standard" centre tapped topology leads to a ripple on the +V rail that is influenced by the balance of the two windings but is clearly going to give me what I need. My question, though is this:

To my untutored eye, this appears to suggest (if we consider the unloaded situation) that the +V rail has a level of filtering determined by the bottom capacitor while the +2V rail is filtered by both top and bottom capacitors in series (i.e. half the capacitance if the capacitors are equal). Is it therefore possible or preferable to adopt alternative filtering strategies in order not to "waste" the capacitance that is filtering the +2V rail?

The simple approach to this is shown in the bottom left - this simply moves the bottom of the +2V filter capacitor to ground rather than +V. This obviously requires a capacitor with a voltage rating of 2V while a minor advantage of the standard arrangement is that each capacitor only sees +V, but I have plenty of 550V capacitors.

As an alternative (if this is an inferior arrangement), is the merit in providing additional filtering in the +2V supply where the filter capacitor is connected to ground rather than +V, as shown in the bottom right?

Comment: I would use the bottom left version because there is less influence from load variations on +2V to the +V supply. Such coupling may introduce unwanted feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have now simulated this in LTSpice and the bottom line is that, per Jens' comment, that bottom left is the optimal configuration. The simple movement of the ground reference embodied by the top right configuration results in much higher ripple voltage on the +2V rail (as the series capacitance is half as effective - halving the filter capacitor for the bottom left topology has the same impact on +2V ripple). It also results (as Jens suggests) in much more of this ripple being transferred onto the +V rail.

It is also illuminating to look at the voltages on the secondary. If the centre tap is left open (so it just becomes a standard full wave rectifier circuit with a +2V output) each end of the transformer has a sinusoidal waveform in antiphase, with the bottom of the sinusoid clamped to 0V through the diodes. I.e. they are essentially antiphase sinewave with a minimum of 0V and a maximum of +2V - the centre tap must sit half way between these two sine waves and, because they are in antiphase, LTSpice confirms that the centre tap sits very stably at +V. However, with a simplistic model for the transformer and without any reservoir capacitor, *any* loading of the centre tap causes the reference voltage of the transformer to be set by the centre tap and transformer secondary waveforms change such that centre tap has an unfiltered full wave signal of amplitude +V. Clearly, adding the reservoir capacitor back in forces the centre tap to remain stable at +V and LTSpice confirms again, that, with the reservoir capacitor on the centre tap, everything reverts back to the waveforms one would expect with the centre tap unloaded.

This is probably not surprising as it confirms that the centre tap does not become magically stable at +V without the need for a reservoir capacitor, even if the unloaded state suggests it might! Instead, one needs to think of the centre tap in this configuration as providing a full wave rectified signal at +V that then needs its filter capacitor in the normal way to minimise the ripple.